# Although I change the text of label it still returns initial value, how can I solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Although I assign the text to the label (lblDoc), for

```
<%FillRpt(rpt, lblDoc.Text , UserId);%>
```

lblDoc.Text is Label.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDoc" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

I changed the Text value but still it return "Label". How can I change it?

the case is below:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "FileManager.aspx/foo",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#<%=lblDoc.ClientID%>").text(selectedPath);
                    <%FillRpt(rpt, lblDoc.Text , UserId);%>
                },
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem via using Web Method which return JSON data.

And after that

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 
                data: 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                   //.........
                    });
                },
                error: function(msg) {

                },
            });
```

in the success part, I do what I want. For example I append some data to any tag such as

```
$("#stackOverflow").append(....)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are updating the **client representation of a `Label` control on the client browser**, but this  value won't be read on the server code for two reasons:

- When you do an HTML post on a page, only the *form input fields* are sent to the server, the `Label` control renders as a `<span id="<ClientID>">` therefore the content of the span won't be sent as data to the server
- Even if the `span` content tag were sent to the server, its value **would be overridden with the `Label` value stored in the *ViewState***

Your code won't work the way you are trying for the above reasons, and (as far as I know) the `ViewState` field cannot be decrypted using JavaScript

As an alternative:

1. Keep changing the text of the `span` tag representing the `Label`
2. Add a hidden field, and when you change the `Label` text in JavaScript, replicate the same value in this hidden field, finally, in your server code use this value to change the `Label.Text` property

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the <% tags?  You should just be able to do :

```
$("#lblDoc").text(selectedPath);
```

Comment: because my lblDoc is an asp.net control.